# Is there any errors with this PHP Code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there any problem with this since i get no output returned?Thanks in advance.

```
$question_text = $_POST['question_text'];

$first_word = explode(" ", $question_text);

$query ="SELECT c.field_name,t.category_name, d.domain_name FROM category_fields c, taxonomy_category t,  taxonomy_domain d
 WHERE c.category_Id = t.category_Id AND t.domain_Id = d.domain_Id
 AND c.field_name = '$first_word'";
```

I've changed my code to this and still no output.Is there a problem with the way i display them ?Thanks

$question_text = $_POST['question_text'];

list($first_word) = explode(' ', $question_text);

$query ="SELECT c.field_name,t.category_name, d.domain_name FROM category_fields c, taxonomy_category t,  taxonomy_domain d WHERE c.category_Id = t.category_Id AND t.domain_Id = d.domain_Id AND c.field_name = '".mysql_escape_string($first_word[0])."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))

{

echo "Keyword :{$row['c.field_name']}" .
         "Category : {$row['t.category_name']}" . 
         "Domain : {$row['d.domain_name']}";
}

?>

Comment: This code is vulnerable to an [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please don't interpolate POST data directly into the query--do some escaping. You might try checking what the value of $first_word is and running the query manually against your db.

Comment: `print_r` is your friend. `print_r($first_word);` will indicate why its not working. Also, `list($first_word) = explode(' ', $question_text);` extracts the first element of the generated array into `$first_word`.

Answer (score 1):

$first_word is an array, not a string, in your query you want **$first_word[0]**

it is also very unsafe to put any user submitted value directly in to a sql query, it should always be sanitised.

Comment: Thanks,so i just have to add the array to both the $first_word ? Query too ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `explode` line you could use following to get a correct SQL query:

```
$first_word = mysql_real_escape_string(strtok($question_text, " "));
```

The `strtok` cuts of the string until the first space.  And escape function is necessary to prevent your script from SQL exploits.

Answer (score 0):

```
list($first_word) = explode(' ', $question_text);
```

This should do the trick. **Sanitize your database inputs!**

Comment: Hi,thanks and i have fixed the code but still no output.Is there any problem ?The new code is added above. –

Comment: Hi **Abby**; When you do `list($first_word) = explode(' ', $question_text);`, you no longer access `$first_word` as an array. The `list()` function extracts from the array result of `explode()`, the first element, and stores it in the supplied argument, in this case `$first_word`. You can simply use `$first_word` in your query. **Sanitize your database inputs!**

Comment: Ok i will look up on the ways to sanitize the inputs since i'm a beginner in PHP :) But a quick question, do i have to have a table to store the question_text in the method POST that i used? Currently i have a database named keyword with 3tables (category_fields,taxonomy_category,taxonomy_domain).I have make it list($first_word) and query just the $first_word bu still im getting Keyword : 
Category : 
Domain : 
It did not display the 1 i've stated in query.

Answer (score 0):

Well after `$first_word = explode(" ", $question_text);` 
`$first_word` is an array because `explode` returns and array

Therefore

```
$query ="SELECT c.field_name,t.category_name, d.domain_name FROM category_fields c, taxonomy_category t,  taxonomy_domain d
 WHERE c.category_Id = t.category_Id AND t.domain_Id = d.domain_Id
 AND c.field_name = '$first_word'";
```

should be

```
$query ="SELECT c.field_name,t.category_name, d.domain_name FROM category_fields c, taxonomy_category t,  taxonomy_domain d
 WHERE c.category_Id = t.category_Id AND t.domain_Id = d.domain_Id
 AND c.field_name = '".mysql_escape_string($first_word[0])."'";
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php for what `mysql_escape_string` does.

Comment: Hi,thanks and i have fixed the code but still no output.Is there any problem ?The new code is added above.